# Include pipe and redirect inside a for loop

Tags: loops, redirect, batch-file, for-loop, pipe

How do I use pipe or redirect inside the cmd for loop?

My sample script is (objective is to see if a series of specific programs / services are running:

```
for  %%m in ( **{list of individual program names}** ) do (
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%m" /NH   ^| find /i "%%m"  
if "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" set /a err_count=%err_count%+1
echo checking tasklist item %%m , count is %err_count%
)
```

I need to pipe through find, or the tasklist will always complete without error, even if the program isn't running.

I've tried every variation I can think of to escape `|` and `>` in the loop, and nothing so far has worked.

The `/f` delimiters option only works if the command is inside the parentheses for line 1. I want the command inside the loop.

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what error or wrong behavior you see vs what you expect to see.  You don't need to escape pipe or redirect inside a `for` loop.  Turn echo on to see what commands your batch file is running.  This works fine:  `for %%m in (chrome.exe abc.exe notepad++.exe) do tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq %%m" /nh | find /i "%%m" >>results.txt`

Comment: Also, you need to use delayed expansion around `err_count` in the loop.  Put `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and then use `!err_count!` in the loop.  Type `help set` on the command line or do a google search for more info.

Answer (score 1):

you must only escape pipe signs, though don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s *_log.xml ^| find "abc" /i /v') do type "%%~i" >> main_log.xml
```

escape |'s don't escape >'s. this is because you are ending a command with a non-escaped pipe. whereas you are simply telling the operating system to change the meanings of the program's STDIN and STDOUT with > < >> and <<. also use % not %% at command-line

Answer (score 0):

The delayed expansion is a common way to use a variable within a loop, with the !variable! syntax.

A pipe is a normal character within a loop and doesn't need to be escaped.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for  %%m in ( **{list of individual program names}** ) do (
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%m" /NH    | find /i "%%m"  
if errorlevel 1 set /a err_count+=1
echo checking tasklist item %%m , count is !err_count!
)
```